# Customer Login, Registration, Forgot password on single page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, validation, form-validation

> By using this [link](http://astrio.net/blog/magento-registration-login)  , I have displayed customer login, registration and forgot password on a single page i.e. on login page (/index.php/customer/account/login/)

But now, **for login and registration fields, validations are not working**. When I click on Login or Registration button with improper input, page reloads and then error messages are displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Form prototype validation block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
        var customForm = new VarienForm('my-custom-form');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Check for the id used in form that might be causing the issue

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you very much for your help.